# Get users from groups in active directory, disposing of everything

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to get active directory groups with their users, all while disposing of all `IDisposable` assets when they reach the end of their usefulness. The groups and users are passed into a method that extracts certain properties and adds them to `ExpandoObjects`. This requires a decent number of nested `using` blocks.

Since the method is private, and most of the variables only exist in the `using` blocks, I gave the variables very short names. Naming them properly as `groupPrincipal` or `principalSearchResult` would involve breaking even more lines to fit the long names.

```
private IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> GetOuGroupsUsersData(
    PrincipalContext pc)
{
    var data = new List<ExpandoObject>();
    using (var gp = new GroupPrincipal(pc))
    {
        using (var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(gp))
        {
            using (var psr = ps.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (var g in psr.GetGroupPrincipals())
                {
                    using (var gpsr = g.GetMembers())
                    {
                        data.AddRange(
                            gpsr.GetUserPrincipals().Select(
                                u => GenerateData(g, u))
                                .Cast<ExpandoObject>());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to reduce the number of `using` blocks? Am I even disposing of everything properly?

Comment: I don't see any lines in that snippet that wouldn't fit on the screen if you actually used meaningful variable names.  You only use one or two variables per line, and you've still got lots of free horizontal space.

Comment: @Servy Bear in mind that this code in the file is indented twice, once for the namespace and once for the class. After that, the line `foreach (var groupPrincipal in principalSearchResult.GetGroupPrincipals())` is indented six times and with the names spelled out like that, is 98 chars long.

Comment: Then don't intent the code so much; clearly it's not aiding readability.  Of course, if you *really* want to keep them, then just refactor that portion out into a method.

Answer (score 5):

1. You can remove braces between `using` statements, leaving the last one. That would help you to remove a few of lines, but still not so deeply.
2. Wrapping the `IDisposable` interface is a good choice to do as an alternative to a dozen of `using` statements.
3. I'd suggest you using more appropriate names, maybe by lowercasing just a character of your class/method when you instantiate/call them.

Add this class to your project:

```
    public class IDisposableList : List<IDisposable>, IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this.Count > 0)
            {
                List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();

                foreach (var disposableItem in this)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        disposableItem.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        exceptions.Add(ex);
                    }
                }

                base.Clear();

                if (exceptions.Count > 0)
                    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
            }
        }

        public T Add<T>(Func<T> item) where T : IDisposable
        {
            var disposable = item();
            base.Add(disposable);

            return disposable;
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
            var data = new List<ExpandoObject>();

            using (var disposables = new IDisposableList())
            {

                var gp = disposables.Add(() => new GroupPrincipal(pc));

                var ps = disposables.Add(() => new PrincipalSearcher(gp));

                var psr = disposables.Add(() => ps.FindAll());

                foreach (var g in psr.GetGroupPrincipals())
                {

                    var gpsr = disposables.Add(() => g.GetMembers());

                    data.AddRange(
                            gpsr.GetUserPrincipals().Select(
                                u => GenerateData(g, u))
                                .Cast<ExpandoObject>());

                }

            }
```

this is just a more elegant way to do what you asked.

Remember that using a `foreach` is not as performant as a `for` loop.

Comment: care to join me in [The Second Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and help me to understand why you don't like my suggestion?  I am open to learning more about C# than I already do.  thank you

Comment: @Malachi it's not I don't like your suggestion, it's just not correct because the resource will be disposed just after everything is done inside the context of the `using` statement, that's why it may run faster for you. Why should we chat, instead of showing our discussion to the OP? Maybe he will be able to validate our suggestions, if he will still be able to see our comments.

Comment: because it is a long conversation that is not necessarily about the OP's code at all

Comment: @Malachi rather it's necessary to make a discussion here. He could follow your suggestion of returning before the using statement is completely finished and without awareness, which isn't right. Please, elaborate if you need to contradict me.

Comment: @Malachi thank you for strutting about something [we've already talked about in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/conversation/using-statement-return) and for downvoting just because I forgot to edit it after both us realized we were wrong when we saw the IL code. Yes, you were wrong too, as you speculated it was faster.

Comment: I did not realize that it was left from before the conversation in Chat yesterday, I apologize.

Answer (score 4):

like ExtremeCSharper said, you can remove some of the Curly Braces for the using statements. you should also return as soon as possible, so inside the using statement.

this is how I would clean it up

```
private IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> GetOuGroupsUsersData(
    PrincipalContext pc)
{
    var data = new List<ExpandoObject>();
    using (var gp = new GroupPrincipal(pc))
    using (var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(gp))
    using (var psr = ps.FindAll())
    {
        foreach (var g in psr.GetGroupPrincipals())
        {
            using (var gpsr = g.GetMembers())
            {
                data.AddRange(
                    gpsr.GetUserPrincipals().Select(
                        u => GenerateData(g, u))
                        .Cast<ExpandoObject>());
            }
        }    
        return data;
    }
}
```

The reason that I would write it this way is because I want to return the data before I do the clean up and dispose all the things I just opened.

If I were to write this the old school way, with try/catch/finally it would look like this (I left out the catches because we don't want to catch anything we just want to make sure that everything is disposed of to prevent memory leaks)

```
private IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> GetOuGroupsUsersData(
    PrincipalContext pc)
{
    var data = new List<ExpandoObject>();
    try {
        var gp = new GroupPrincipal(pc);
        var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(gp);
        var psr = ps.FindAll();
        foreach (var g in psr.GetGroupPrincipals())
        {
            try {
                var gpsr = g.GetMembers();
                data.AddRange(
                    gpsr.GetUserPrincipals().Select(
                        u => GenerateData(g, u))
                        .Cast<ExpandoObject>());
            }
            finally{
                gpsr.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    finally {
        gp.Dispose();
        ps.Dispose();
        psr.Dispose();
    }
    //Here is where you were returning the variable 
}
```

To me, it looks right to return from inside the block.

I really want my code to tell a story, I don't want to be burdened with remembering all the clean up stuff, so that is why I use the using blocks, I return as soon as I can because that is the end of the story I am telling.  and inside the main using block, after the foreach is the first spot that I can return, no need to keep reading.

Comment: Where you put the return is a bit subjective and largely down to personal preference.  The method still has to perform the finally block before `data` is returned.  In this particular situation, I would put the return statement after the using blocks, because where a method has only one return, I like it to be at the end.  However where the method has multiple returns (for example parameter validation) I'd probably agree with you and put it in the using block.

Comment: Does the assembly look different depending on where the return is (is the behavior different/better either way)?

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris [we talked about it a little over 12 hours ago in Chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/conversation/using-statement-return)

Comment: @forsvarir, you are right, it is really a preference, i haven't been able to find anything so far to say that it is a standard or anything.  if I were to review the code I would ask "why put the return outside of the using statement?"

Comment: @Malachi because "the last thing the method needs to do is return its result" :). Don't get me wrong, I think you have a valid point, which is why I voted, but I think where I put the return depends a lot on what the contents of the rest of the method looks like (probably as well as other irrelevant things like what else I've done that day which impact the way I'm thinking etc)